# Unit testing Drools File

Tags: java, unit-testing, drools, kie

I am trying to Unit test drools files. I pass in the directory for the file adn the drools file itself as a String

```
public ObjectToRunDroolsOn runDrools(ObjectToRunDroolsOn objectToRunDroolsOn, String droolsFileDirectory, String droolsFile) {

    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(droolsFileDirectory, droolsFile);
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
    ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);
    KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();

    kieSession.insert(objectToRunDroolsOn);

    kieSession.fireAllRules();

    return objectToRunDroolsOn;
}
```

When I run the code through my application everything works fine but when I call the code from a unit test the everything seems as in it does not throw any errors but also does not make any changes when the rules are fired

Do you need to do something in the unit test (e.g. set a KIE session) ?

Comment: Is the `droolsFileDirectory` a fixed, full qualified path? Or is it a relative path that is calculated in runtime? Just make sure that, when running your unit tests, the KieBase actually contains your rules.

Comment: this is a hard coded string that is constant, it isn't generated or anything strange like that (e.g. "src/main/resources/rule.drl", "src/test/resources/rule.drl")

Comment: The path looks extremely suspicious to me. It is a relative path that has to be resolved in some way. If you are using maven to build your project and run your tests, the path looks plain wrong (unless you have a really strange directory structure). Just check what rules do you have in your KieBase after you build it in your test. My guess is 0.

Comment: All the examples I look up show to use a path similar to this, and this path ("src/main/resources/rule.drl") works fine when I run the application, but 0 rules fire when I use the test path ("src/test/resources/rule.drl") when running the unit tests, not sure if it is the path or something else that is causing 0 rules to be fired

Comment: Check how many rules you HAVE in your KieBase after it is built. If you don't have any, then the problem is probably the path. If you have all your rules, but they are not working properly, then the problem could be related to the data you are inserting.

Comment: It is also a good idea to `validate ()` the `KieContainer` to check that there are no compilation errors.

Comment: I can see from the KieBase that no pkgs (packages) or anything is read in from the drools file I am passing in so it looks like the issue is it is not reading the file. I will look to see if I change the path or use a Resource will this resolve it